# how to find bash script, then execute it and pass some arguments

Tags: bash, shell, find

how to write the command??

I tried `find . -name test.bash | xargs bash dd`, this threw an error `bash: xx: No such file or directory`

I also tried `find . -name test.bash | xargs bash -c`, can't work too.

Comment: Added code formatting tags.

Comment: If the script is in the current directory`bash script-name arg1 arg2 ...... argn`.  If it is in another directory then that directory should be in `$PATH`, it should be executable, and it should have a `#!` line.

Comment: Voting to close : "Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a **clear problem statement* are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example]https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" . Good luck.

Comment: What happens when you run `find . -name test.bash` does it find anything?

Comment: @Freiheit it returns `./test.bash`

Comment: @cdarke I knows this way, I want to know how to transfer arguments when I  find file from `find` command and execute it.

Comment: So `dd` is supposed to be an argument to the script? (To be clear, when you run `xargs bash dd`, then you get `bash dd /path/to/script` invoked -- and the `dd` command doesn't know how to parse that argument).

Comment: Please also review the output from `xargs` with the `-t` (AKA `--verbose`) option. This will make xargs print out the command and argument it runs. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created a test script, super simple, it just prints the arguments.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$@"
```

Then I find it in it's directory and call it with arguments:

```
find . -name test.bash -exec {} arg1 arg2 \;
```

It runs and outputs "arg1 arg2".

Comment: @fujian26: good morning, please accept the answer (check mark on the left of the question).